# Why is my canvas only loading the images in the top left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a program that will make video game maps. It worked perfectly fine before, but I added a variable, pixelWideAndTall, to automatically set the width and height of the canvas, and now it will only load the images in the top left corner. I just want to know why that is happening and how to fix it. If you need to see it, you'll have to copy and paste the code into whichever text editor you use. I would post a picture, but my reputation isn't high enough.
Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('paper');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var posX=0;                                                   //All of my variables
    var posY=0; 
    var pixelWideAndTall = prompt('How wide and tall do you want each picture to be? Make sure it\'s a number, please!');
    while(isNaN(pixelWideAndTall)){
        pixelWideAndTall = prompt('Alright, put in a number this time.');
    }
    var map = [
    [0,0,1,0,0],       //Map
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0]];
    canvas.height = map.length * pixelWideAndTall;
    canvas.width = map[0].length * pixelWideAndTall;

    //Now for the pictures!

    var grass = new Image();
    grass.src='https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/v/t1.0-9/10252096_483877768405708_6915128458002047622_n.jpg?oh=0dd45ac8392b31dd89da67f2b74e0eef&oe=53ABDB2A&__gda__=1404253465_7ee03498efb21d7759862a3268769775';
    var sand = new Image();
    sand.src='https://scontent-b-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10169458_483877771739041_423139715070437533_n.jpg';
    var logA = new Image();
    logA.src='https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/10014648_483877575072394_6204441713213423736_n.jpg';
    var logB = new Image();
    logB.src='https://scontent-a-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10247323_483877578405727_3664131849980667819_n.jpg';

    for(var i=0;i<map.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<map[i].length;j++){
            switch(map[i][j]){
                case 0:
                    c.drawImage(grass,posX,posY,pixelWideAndTall,pixelWideAndTall);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    c.drawImage(sand,posX,posY,pixelWideAndTall,pixelWideAndTall);

                    /*Loops through every spot of the array. Based on what's 
                    in that particular index, it draws a certain picture. */     

                    break;                                                                                          
                case 2:
                    c.drawImage(logA,posX,posY,pixelWideAndTall,pixelWideAndTall);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    c.drawImage(logB,posX,posY,pixelWideAndTall,pixelWideAndTall);
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('You must have put in an input that isn\'t supported yet. Please fix!');
                    break;
            }
            posX+=pixelWideAndTall;
        }
        posX=0;
        posY+=pixelWideAndTall;
    }
}
</script>
<style>
#paper{
    border:3px solid black;
}
p{
    font-size:6px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>                                                                       <!-- Just in case... -->
<canvas id='paper' height = 0 width = 0>Your browser does not support the HTML5 Canvas element. Either try a different browser, or just give it up.</canvas>
<p>You <strong><em>may</em></strong> need to refresh a few times for the image to load. Thank you!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `pixelWideAndTall` variable is a string when returned from prompt.

It get converted to number when multiply is used which is why it works with this line:

```
canvas.height = map.length * pixelWideAndTall;
```

but not when *adding* - so what is happening is that the value is concatenated as a string instead at the plus operator with the posX etc. in the loop.

To fix simply force it to a number right away:

```
var pixelWideAndTall = prompt('...');
while(isNaN(pixelWideAndTall)){
    pixelWideAndTall = prompt('Alright, put in a number this time.');
}

pixelWideAndTall *= 1;  // this will force it to a number
```

optionally:

```
pixelWideAndTall = parseInt(pixelWideAndTall, 10);
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/KMhFW/)**

PS: You should really consider implementing an [image loader for the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246641/draw-image-on-canvas-after-load-into-array/22262655#22262655).

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, Cryptoburner! I can't believe it was that simple! When I get 15 reputation, I'll definitely vote your answer up, don't worry! :D

Comment: @Ctsmario no problem! the simplest of problems some times tend to escape the rader. Happens to us all :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, again! Now, this is my question: Why would the 4 images in the top-left corner load, but not any of the others?

Comment: @Ctsmario the images aren't loaded correctly so it's a game of lottery. Image loading is asynchronous and the images may or may not be available (depending on browser cache, computer performance etc.) when you try to use them. See the link at the bottom of the answer for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't understand much of it yet, as I am relatively new to Javascript, but I will certainly try it! :)

Comment: @Ctsmario in that case an already image loader may be a better option. Why not check out my [YAIL2](https://github.com/epistemex/YAIL2-images-loader-for-JavaScript) loader (it's all free).